Vue - passing a data list to child component
I've looked over a few answers on here like this one and as far as I can see this should work to pass imported JSON data from the parent to the child component.
The import and looping through data works fine if I do it all in the parent with a v-for:
<div v-for="(product, index) in productData" :key="index">{{product}}</div>

But I just can't get it to work if the loop is done in the child component.
Parent Component
<script>
import productData from './assets/products.json'
import ChildComponent from './components/ChildComponent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    ChildComponent
  },
  data(){
    return{
      productData: productData.products
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <ChildComponent :productsData="productData" />
</template>

Child Component
<template>
  <div v-for="(product, index) in productData" :key="index">{{product}}</div>
</template>

However this doesn't render the looped data like it did when done in just the parent component and I can't see what's wrong from researching.

Did you define your prop inside the child element?

Also you pass productsData and then you loop productData in child?

Both relevant to the example code, I believe I experimented with both productData and productsData in my code just in case there was a conflict in reusing that name and I think I just forgot to remove the 's' again from where I was passing the prop in this example. I've upvoted both as are valid here but it was defining the array in the child's prop was what I was missing and the main issue.


Props - Vue Docs
Vue.js 2 passing prop object to child component - StackOverflow answer

ParentComponent.vue
<template>
  <ChildComponent :productsData="productData" />
</template>

<script>
import productData from './assets/products.json'
import ChildComponent from './components/ChildComponent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    ChildComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      productData: productData.products
    };
  }
};
</script>

ChildComponent.vue
<template>
  <div v-for="(product, index) in productsData" :key="index">
    {{ product }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ChildComponent',
  props: {
    productsData: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  }
};
</script>


Thank you for this, I had indeed missed setting the props in the export, so thank you for the code reply and the extra links too as it really helped.

I also updated the link in the SO answer you mentioned; it points to the old Vue 2 legacy documentation. I would instead of that recommend the Vue 3 Composition API for better usability.

I think you need to set props in child component.
<script>

export default {
    props: {
        value: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
}

</script>


I can't upvote this even though you were right about missing setting the props in the child component being the issue, as the code answer given isn't correct. value should have been productData to work with the original example given, and String should have been Array
